# Draw and paint areas in images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, area

How to draw areas in a image, based on points, like draw areas in google maps? Dynamically with javascript. 
Editing: The question is about to put a map image on the page and draw an area on the top of a house, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [canvas element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element).

Comment: This will not work in IE unless you use the Google explorecanvas project http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/.

Comment: @Nissan: yes, I remember that now.  It's part of html5, so I guess IE will support it eventually.

Comment: all solutions are great. i'll stay with canvas element, since my client does not care for IE. Initially, I was looking for a JS solution, then I've found those: http://www.c-point.com/javascript_vector_draw.htm and http://jsdraw2d.jsfiction.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) or [VML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language) (IE only). Although canvas tags are certainly the easiest.

I experimented with dynamically created SVG through javascript a while back: [here's](http://sawyourad.com/technobotts/experiments/PursuitCurves.htm) an example usage.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the JavaScript solution, you could always use PHP to dynamically draw lines.  Then place the newly-created image on top of the map image.

Here is a small tutorial: [Drawing shapes with GD](http://www.emirplicanic.com/php/drawing-shapes-with-php.php)